# A set of shader nodes and lights to separate the background from the foreground on a set of videos

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders, light

I'm trying to create a cut out animation with ebsynth + blender. I've got some footage from a scene of a movie and I've recolored the frames where a man is walking and a black man is moving a little bit while he is sitting on a sofa.

I've recolored only the first frame of the scene and I've used it as the frame that ebsynth should use to copy the graphic style from.

As you can see from the images below, the new graphic style stuck on the body for the first steps of the men. But then, when he walks close to the door / window, the brown color of the jacket blends with the brown color of the door, and the grey color of the floor blends with the grey color of the pants.

You can see what happens very clear giving a look here :

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Tx3b85RGyPWUDZOrNgXJ2SejZ4Fv7Ybi

(I don't know why,when I have recompressed the images produced by ebsynth,the video started playing very slowly)

So, I need to fix this wrong fusion of colors.

I've got an idea to achieve this goal. What about to "play" a little with the blender lights to give more contrast to the colors of the floor and of the door / window? or even to the pants or to the jacket of the man? Maybe I can place two lamps on the scene,the first one that gives the right light intensity to the floor and the second one to the door / window.

Or I should create a set of nodes that do the same. I'm not sure if I should to this only for the first frame, the frame used by ebsynth to copy the style from or to each frame of the original movie. I can do that,but my scenario is not so easy. In fact, I'm using 3 planes. On the first one I have projected the texture of the interior of the house, on the second and one I have projected the alpha image of the white man, and on the third one of the black man, as you can see below :

[image]
[image]

So,the lights and the set of nodes should take care of the alpha images of the bodies. Take in consideration that these bodies overlap perfectly over the old ones. When I have created more contrast between the background and the foreground (the alpha images of the bodies), I can separate them easier.

I imagine that for this matter I have also need to another set of shader nodes. That's all. I'm waiting for your precious suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you need shaders. Are you using images as planes? This could be done in the compositor and there you would have control on background and foreground. Just do some form of color correction for the different elements.

Comment: yes,I'm using 3 images as planes. two of them are in the alpha channel,the 3 is the house not. Can u be more specific ? which kind of color correction do u have in mind ?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/206305/how-to-color-correct-an-image-that-i-have-projected-on-a-plane-with-the-alpha-ch